# FCM + iOS + Notification Extension

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, push

I am implementing iOS Push notifications using FCM. But i want to show an image with my notification. That's why I'm leaning towards implementing `UNNotificationServiceExtension`

What I've done is the following. Add a new `target` > `notification service extension`. That target currently contains

[image]

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            // Modify the notification content here...
            bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"
            bestAttemptContent.subtitle = "Hey from extension"

            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}
```

Afterwards i send a push notification with the following payload:

[image]

The push notification gets received etc however it doesn't go through the extension because it does not contain my modified data that i've added in `NotificationService`

What am I missing, how do i make sure my modified extension gets called when receiving a push

Comment: is ur issue resolved?

Comment: yes, it's resolved i've answered my own question

Comment: Facing same problem. I am not getting any call back in `didReceive` function. Where my target is set same for app and extension!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out i needed to match the deployment target of my app with the deployment target of the Push Extension

[image]